# Computation of product of permutations

Tags: python, performance, beginner, combinatorics

Given a graph \$G = (V,E)\$ with a unique labeling of each vertex, let the transposition \$(i,j)\$ (where \$i,j\$ are the labels on adjacent vertices) represent selecting an edge and swapping the labels \$i\$ and \$j\$.

I would like to take a list of edges in a graph (a cube in this code), and determine the number of permutations on \$V\$ that are representable as a product of at most some \$k\$ sets of disjoint transpositions **of the above form**. For example, a permutation \$(62154703)\$ can be expressed as \$[(67)(03)][(37)(56)][(45)(26)](12)\$, where the brackets are only to emphasize the specific disjoint set.

How can I improve my run time? Currently my runtime is about 18 hours. I don't know the runtime of the last step, but currently the first step in CreateAllPermutations takes 2 seconds, and the second step takes 1765 seconds.

Additional question: is the Permutation class from sympy.combinatorics slowing me down?

Here is the input file, and some truncated expected sample output (this output will not be printed, but it *is* what is being generated) from `GetSteps()`, which is a smaller case of `CreateAllPermutations()`, along with what I expect to see from `print(len(allPerms))`:

**Input file:**

> ```
> 01
> 03
> 04
> 12
> 15
> 23
> 26
> 37
> 45
> 47
> 56
> 67
> ```

**Sample output from `GetSteps()` and `allPerms`:**

> ```
> Completed all permutations of 1 step! There are 107 such permutations.
> (4 7)
> (0 1)(2 6)(3 7)
> (0 3)(4 7)
> (7)(0 4)(1 5)
> (7)(0 3)(1 5)(2 6)
> (7)(2 3)(5 6)
> (7)(1 5)(2 3)
> (0 4)(1 5)(2 3)(6 7)
> (7)(2 3)(4 5)
> (0 1)(3 7)(5 6)
> (7)(0 3)
> (1 5)(4 7)
> (6 7)
> (0 4)(1 2)(3 7)
> (0 3)(1 5)(4 7)
>
> 40320 #8!, as I am expecting to generate every permutation on 8 elements
> ```

**Main code:**

```python
import time, itertools
from sympy.combinatorics import Permutation as Perm

def GetEdges():
    edgeFile = open("EdgesQ3.txt","r")
    edges = []
    for line in edgeFile:
        line = line.strip()
        line = list(line)
        for vertex in line:
            line[line.index(vertex)] = int(vertex)
        edges.append([line])

    return edgeFile, edges


def AreDisjoint(s1,s2):
    v1 = {point for edge in s1 for point in edge}
    v2 = {point for edge in s2 for point in edge}
    shared = v1 & v2

    return shared == set()


def GetSteps(edges,maxMatching):
    """The variable maxMatching is to give a value for the maximum number 
    of disjoint permutations in a set"""
    steps = []
    steps.extend(edges)
    for i in range(1,maxMatching):
        for s1 in steps:
            if len(s1) == i:
                for s2 in steps:
                    newStep = []
                    newStep.extend([s for s in s1])
                    newStep.extend([s for s in s2])
                    newStep.sort()
                    if AreDisjoint(s1,s2) and newStep not in steps:
                        steps.append(newStep)

    return steps


def CreateOneStepPermutations(steps, size):
    oneStep = set()
    for step in steps:
        perm = Perm([],size = size)
        for edge in step:
            perm *= Perm([edge], size = size)
        oneStep = oneStep | {perm}  
    print("Completed all permutations of 1 step! There are {} such permutations.".format(len(oneStep)), flush = True)

    return oneStep    


def CreateStepDictionary(oneStep):
    stepDict = {}
    stepDict[1] = oneStep

    return stepDict


def CreateAllPermutations(oneStep,stepDict):
    allPerms = set()
    for i in range(1,4):
        count = 0
        routing = set()
        for p1 in stepDict[1]:
            for p2 in stepDict[i]:
                p = p1 * p2
                routing = routing | {p}
                count += 1
                if count % 100 == 0:
                    print("You have computed {} permutations in this block.".format(count), flush = True)

        for j in range(1,i+1):
            routing = routing - set(stepDict[j])
        stepDict[i+1] = routing
        print("Completed all permutations of {} steps! There are {} such permutations.".format(i+1, len(routing)), flush = True)

    for i in range(1,5):
        allPerms = allPerms | stepDict[i]

    return allPerms


def main():
    maxMatching = 4
    vertexSetSize = 8
    edgeFile, edges = GetEdges()
    steps = GetSteps(edges, maxMatching)
    oneStep = CreateOneStepPermutations(steps, vertexSetSize)
    stepDict = CreateStepDictionary(oneStep)
    allPerms = CreateAllPermutations(oneStep, stepDict)

    print(len(allPerms)) #Tells me how much of the symmetric group I get


main()
```

Comment: Could you also supply the input-file and expected output. (Also for smaller cases). This way we could actually run the code to see where speed can be achieved.

Comment: *a product of at most some $k$ sets of disjoint transpositions*" is ambiguous. What I think I get from the code is that no vertex occurs in more than one transposition of any given set, but that the $k$ sets are not necessarily disjoint with each other. Is that interpretation correct?

Comment: Could you provide run times until each major step? E.g. a simple C# implementation takes 4ms to generate the original edges (directly, not loading them from a file); a further 3.5ms to generate products of 2 sets; a further 149ms to generate products of 3 sets, and a further 1.25s to generate products of 4 sets. Comparison with your runtimes may help to pin out the inefficient operations (although I'm inclined to suspect that sympy.Permutation doesn't have a hashcode and the set operations are devolving to worst case).

Comment: I just put in the information for runtime and input-output expectations. Thanks!

Comment: why `range(1, 4)` in `CreateAllPermutations`?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @codesparkle, I am looking for the least `k` such that each permutation in S_n can be decomposed into a product of at most `k` permutations from `CreateOneStepPermutations()`. I just happen to know that in the given example, `k=4`. I was cheating a bit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Fixing the bottleneck

Profiling with `python -m cProfile perm.py` and an early abort showed that `permutation.py` from sympy was accounting for less than 3% of the runtime. The big bottleneck was in `CreateAllPermutations` itself.

Armed with that and a hunch I made the simple change of

```
                routing.add(p)
```

in place of

```
                routing = routing | {p}
```

and (once I'd modified the debug output to be less frequent) the entire program ran to execution in 75 seconds. It's still painfully slow compared to my C# implementation using a handrolled permutation class (1.5 seconds), but it's a massive improvement.

Run again under the profiler, it takes 105.676 seconds of which the bulk of the time goes to `{method 'add' of 'set' objects}` (57.537s), `basic.py(__eq__)` (37.974s), and `permutations.py(__mul__)` (36.705s). So further speedups might be possible by hand-rolling a permutation class, but the real possibilities lie in changing the set representation. Since you're working over a very finite universe, a bit set might be a possibility.

Of course, the disadvantage would be a loss of readability. On that subject, I have some suggestions.

### Readability

```
def AreDisjoint(s1,s2):
    v1 = {point for edge in s1 for point in edge}
    v2 = {point for edge in s2 for point in edge}
    shared = v1 & v2

    return shared == set()
```

I had to think quite hard to work out what this is doing. I'm still not entirely sure why it's working with arrays rather than `Perm` objects, given that you're using those elsewhere. How about something along these lines?

```
def AreDisjoint(p1,p2):
    """Tests whether two permutations avoid both moving the same element"""
    v1 = set(p1.support())
    v2 = set(p2.support())
    return len(v1 & v2) == 0
```

This would mean that `GetSteps` would need to be reworked to use `Perm` objects, so it might as well be refactored into `CreateOneStepPermutations`. There's an additional opportunity there to use the same approach as in `CreateAllPermutations`: instead of sticking everything in one array and having to do tests like

```
            if len(s1) == i:
```

you can build up the sets of different sizes in different layers. I think that it would be almost identical to `CreateAllPermutations` except for the addition of the `AreDisjoint` test. It might even be worthwhile refactoring them into a single method with an argument which is a "can these two permutations be combined?" predicate (passing `AreDisjoint` while building `oneStep`, and a method which always returns `True` while building S_8).

---

I don't see the point of `CreateStepDictionary`. In my opinion it would be clearer to make `CreateAllPermutations` take `oneStep` and immediately construct `stepDict = {1: oneStep}`

---

```
        for j in range(1,i+1):
            routing = routing - set(stepDict[j])
```

is presumably intended to be a speed optimisation, but I don't think it makes much difference. At each layer you will recover the previous layer anyway because the `oneStep` permutations have order 2 by construction, and so are self-inverse. (On timing it to check: removing that step takes us from 75s to 85s, but allows adding in an early return when `len(routing) == 40320` which reduces the runtime to 14s).

```
def CreateAllPermutations(oneStep):
    stepDict = { 1 : oneStep }
    for i in range(1,4):
        routing = set()
        for p1 in stepDict[1]:
            for p2 in stepDict[i]:
                routing.add(p1 * p2)
                if (len(routing)) == 40320: return routing

        stepDict[i+1] = routing

    return routing
```

Obviously that's a bit hacky, and the magic number should at the very least be an argument.

---

One possible further optimisation would be a meet-in-the-middle approach. You can find more detailed descriptions of the principle in the context of e.g. Rubik's cube solving, but here's the basic idea. You want to find the least `n` such that starting with the generators in `oneStep` you generate the (finite) group `G` (here `S_8`). For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that the identity element `e` is in `oneStep`. Then we're looking for `n` such that for each element `u in G` there is a sequence `g_1 * g_2 * ... * g_n = u`.

The approach you're currently using builds up these sequences from one end. But you could equally well build them up from the other end. `g_1 * g_2 * ... * g_n = u` can equally well be written `g_1 * ... * g_i = u * g_n^{-1} * ... * g_{i+1}^{-1}` (and in this case, since each generator is self-inverse, `g_1 * ... * g_i = u * g_n * ... * g_{i+1}`).

That leads to the more complicated (and not tested - beware!) but perhaps more efficient

```
def CreateAllPermutations(oneStep, fullGroup):
    targetSize = len(fullGroup)
    stepDict = { 1 : oneStep }
    for i in range(1,4):
        routing = set(stepDict[i])
        if len(stepDict[i]) * 2 < targetSize:
            for p1 in stepDict[1]:
                for p2 in stepDict[i]:
                    routing.add(p1 * p2)
                    if (len(routing)) == targetSize: return routing
        else:
            # Not-yet-found elements of fullGroup
            diff = set(fullGroup) - stepDict[i]
            for p1 in stepDict[1]:
                for p2 in diff:
                    if (stepDict[i].contains(p2 * p1)):
                        routing.add(p2)
                        if (len(routing)) == targetSize: return routing

        stepDict[i+1] = routing

    return routing
```

Note that sympy.permutation has some methods to generate the symmetric group over a base set, so constructing `fullGroup` can be delegated to them.

Comment: @JazzyMatrix, `add` calculates where to look for the element and tests whether it's there: if not, it adds it. If you add a separate test then it will do the test twice, and will almost certainly make things slower. I did have one further idea for a speedup: since the `oneStep` elements are self-inverse, once you've found more than half of the symmetric group it's probably quicker to iterate through the ones you haven't found, applying each `p in oneStep` and seeing whether you get an already-found element, than to iterate through the found elements.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain that a little more? It sounds to me like this would require creating the symmetric group, and then trying to decompose permutations instead of building them. Also, could it be faster to keep `routing` as a total of all permutations computed, set `stepDict[i]` to `routing` and *then* remove all prior permutations from `stepDict[i]`?

Comment: @JazzyMatrix, pretty much, yes. I've added a section which goes into more detail.